# Is there a proper name for a directed graph with one source and one destination?

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory

The question says it all. Is there a name for a specific type of directed graph which contains only one source and one destination?

Comment: Do you mean that it contains precisely two vertexes $x$ and $y$, and all arrows have source $x$ and target $y$? Also, are we allowing multiple arrows?

Comment: No, the graph can contain many vertices. The only restriction is that there is one source and one destination in the graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you also have a capacity function, it's called [flow network (or a transportation network)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_network).

I don't think there is a special name if the capacity is not involved.